# How about deriving $\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(X X^T \mathbb{E}\left[X X^T\right]\right)\right]= \|\mathbb{E}\left[X X^T\right]\|_F^2$

Tags: expected-value, matrix-equations

The following is from the paper [The Modern Mathematics of Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.04026) page 29. It is the source of my question.

I don't know how to prove the formula in the title? I think equation (1) is equivalent to the formula in the title. Once the formula of the title is proved, the following formula can be proved. So I want someone to help me to prove title. Could anybody help me?

> Let us focus on a single sample $m=1$ and features $X$ that take values in $\mathcal{X}=\{-1,1\}^d.$ Then it holds that $\Sigma^{+}=\frac{X^{(1)}(X^{(1)})^T}{\left\|X^{(1)}\right\|^4}=\frac{X^{(1)}\left(X^{(1)}\right)^{T}}{d^{2}}$ and thus
> $$\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma^{+} \mathbb{E}\left[X X^T\right]\right)\right]=\frac{1}{d^2}\left\|\mathbb{E}\left[X X^T\right]\right\|_F^2 \tag{1}$$

Comment: here's the title derivation: Let $M:= \mathbb{E}\left[X X^{T}\right]$.  Then   

$\mathbb{E}\left[Tr(X X^{T} M)\right]=Tr\Big(\mathbb{E}\left[(X X^{T}) M\right]\Big)=Tr\Big(\mathbb{E}\left[X X^{T}\right]M\Big)=Tr\Big(MM\Big)=\left\|M\right\|_{F}^{2}$ ... I'm not sure what is being asked in the block quote in your original post.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you for your help. I revise the question. And if you prefer, you could write an answer, not a comment.